# Wordpress replace all 404 http header with 410

Tags: php, wordpress, code-snippets

Im trying to replace all 404 error code with 410 gone request which is good for SEO
I have tried the following snippet from [TheDevBlog Post](https://www.thedev.blog/3300/wordpress-replace-404-error-with-410-gone/)

```
if ( is_404() ) {
            define( 'DONOTCACHEPAGE', true );       // WP Super Cache and W3 Total Cache recognise this
            status_header( 410 ); }
```

This is not working, i have checked the syntax & they are correct, why is it not working? what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add 410.php to your theme directory.

You can create 410.php and copy the page template to see the result.

Comment: As you have instructed i have created a 410.php and added 'header("HTTP/1.0 410 Gone");' but not working

Comment: what's inside 410.php file? Have you added header footer to that file?

Comment: I have copied the 404.php and used it as 410.php and added header("HTTP/1.0 410 Gone"); is there something I'm missing 410.php also include get_header(); directive?

Answer (score 0):

Here what you are looking to achieve.

```
<?php
if ( is_404() ) {
header( "HTTP/1.1 410 Gone" ); } ?>
```

This will replace all 404 status to 410 .